# Collapse/merge/shift columns up in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry I'm new at posting questions and I have looked at some python documentations but cannot find what I need with groupby, melt, merge, etc.
I have the following dataframe with 3 columns(function, request, response) in python:

```
function    request         response
status      {Status: CALCULATING}   
status      {Status: CALCULATED}    
status      {Status: NONE}  
temperature                 {60}
temperature {Front} 
temperature                 {60}
temperature {Front} 
temperature                 {59}
temperature {Rear}  
temperature                 {59}
temperature {Rear}
```

and I want to "collapse" the rows upward so the dataframe looks like this:

```
function    request             response
status      {Status: CALCULATING}   
status      {Status: CALCULATED}    
status      {Status: NONE}  
temperature {Front}             {60}
temperature {Front}             {60}
temperature {Rear}              {59}
temperature {Rear}              {59}
```

Could someone help me with this please?  Also, Sorry for the hard to read table. I can't figure out how to post the table correctly when I copy & pasted from an excel output file.  Thanks!

Comment: Try using `df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx')` to read your excel file and convert it to a pandas dataframe

Comment: Thanks @rahlf23, I have the data in a dataframe.  In the end of my code I export it to an excel file so I can pass it to my colleague later.  For now I have both formats

Answer (score 0):

its a bit ugly, but you could group the dataframe by `function` and do the shift-concat-skip if `function == 'temperature'`, else leave the data untouched.

```
df.groupby('function').apply(
   lambda x: x['request response'].str.cat(x['request response'].shift(), ' ')[1::2] 
             if all(x['function'] == 'temperature') else x['request response']
).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
# outputs:
      function       request response
0       status  {Status: CALCULATING}
1       status   {Status: CALCULATED}
2       status         {Status: NONE}
3  temperature           {Front} {60}
4  temperature           {Front} {60}
5  temperature            {Rear} {59}
6  temperature            {Rear} {59}
```